# Wake Windows 7 from sleep and modifier keys are reversed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Here is my first attempt to write this question while I had the issue. Because of the issue, I was unable to click on the post question button:

> I just woke my computer from sleep and my keyboard is not behaving.
>
> For example, the modifier keys are reversed so pressing <kbd>arrow left</kbd>
> highlights text rather than moving the cursor. I also have my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>
> key reversed, and I get a `<` when I try to type a comma and a `>` when I
> type a fullstop, yet holding or not holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> does not correct this.
>
> I have tried unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in using a
> different USB port with no improvement.
>
> In the past, the only solution I've found is to reboot the system. Else
> I'm stuck holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to click on links so they don't open in new
> windows, etc.

After restarting my computer I'm tempted to put the punctuation in above. Basically, all the modifier keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> had been reversed so that the lights and the key combinations did not work as expected, and using my computer became far more  difficult. For example, I could click on some text, and click elsewhere, and it would select everything inbetween as if I had held the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

This has happened several times and always when I've woke my computer from sleep.

**Note:** It's not sticky keys, it was one of the first things I checked for

Comment: That sounds weird! :)  What kind of keyboard is it?

Comment: It's a £2.99 standard UK layout USB keyboard I got from Argos, I've had it for years and it's worked perfectly fine, no fancy features, no backlit keys or media buttons, uses the standard Windows keyboard drivers

Comment: That reads to me like one of the shift keys is stuck down.  Is there a behaviour that isn't accounted for by a stuck shift-key?

Comment: yes, when I hold the shift key It does the reverse of what I would normally expect it to do. If it were stuck there would be no change when held down/rebooted. It also doesn't explain the capslock reverse, the alt key or the ctrl key

Comment: ( on both sides of the keyboard too, not just the left/right )

Comment: I have no idea what the cause of this might be, but did you test it with a different keyboard? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: The only other keyboard I have to plugin has been sitting in a cupboard because it's broken ( damned saitek cyborg ), although that broke years before I built this computer

Answer (score 1):

The feature that provides the functionality of what you are experiencing is called [StickyKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StickyKeys). It's not new to Windows 7, and it has been in since at least Windows XP that I know of, possibly earlier.

To disable in Windows 7:
Menu *Start* -> *Control Panel* -> *Ease of Access* -> Change how your keyboard works (or make the keyboard easier to use) ->

All your settings are in here. I personally untick everything when I build a new PC. Make sure nothing is ticked and also go into setup StickyKeys and untick anything in here.

I cannot explain why coming out of sleep is causing this, but hopefully this should stop it from happening.

Comment: I play a lot of RTS games, which means sticky keys comes on a lot when holding shift to queue orders, so disabling sticky keys was one of the first things I did when I set up this machine

Comment: personally then I would re-install - I have no idea why this might be happening, especially if you've already disabled that.

Answer (score 0):

This does happen in some Windows versions. Particularly confusing if you are trying to enter a password, it might explain some of the cases where one's login stops working for no good reason!

An alternative method that usually works for me is pressing in this sequence:

Left shift, left ctrl, left alt, right alt, right ctrl, right shift.

Then see if you are able to switch caps lock on and off as normal.